# Adding Language to tesseract 4 on macOS?

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew, tesseract, tesseract.js

I have tesseract 4 installed. It works with German, English etc. I want to add a language, say Latin.

I have downloaded the file `lat.traineddata` from [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Data-Files), for tesseract 4. Now I'd like to install this file so that I can use it with tesseract. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to run `brew install tesseract-lang` to install all available languages, if you have a custom one, you can try copying it to `/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/<version>/share/tessdata/`

Answer (score 0):

I think just running `brew install tesseract-lang` should work fine on OSX.